# Reordering matrices based on column titles in Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting, matrix

The question involves reordering matrices based on the titles of their columns. The input matrices are provided, along with the desired output matrices. The task is to rearrange the matrices so that the columns follow a specific order defined by the titles.

Keep in mind that the appearance of all the columns is not mandatory, that is, there could be a matrix without any column with a title L followed by a number and yet it should order the rest of the elements that are there. Both the X followed by a number, the U followed by a number and the L followed by a number must also be ordered according to the number that accompanies them.

This is my code, but it give me an error like this:

```
    reordered_matrix.extend([matrix[titles.index(col)] for col in x_columns])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here the code:

```py
def reorder_matrix(matrix):
    titles = matrix[0]  # Get the column titles
    reordered_matrix = [titles]  # Initialize the reordered matrix with the titles

    # Determine the order of column types: X, U, L
    x_columns = [col for col in titles if col.startswith('X')]
    u_columns = [col for col in titles if col.startswith('U')]
    l_columns = [col for col in titles if col.startswith('L')]

    # Add columns to the reordered matrix based on the determined order
    reordered_matrix.extend([matrix[titles.index(col)] for col in ['C', 'X', 'B']])
    reordered_matrix.extend([matrix[titles.index(col)] for col in x_columns])
    reordered_matrix.extend([matrix[titles.index(col)] for col in u_columns])
    reordered_matrix.extend([matrix[titles.index(col)] for col in l_columns])

    return reordered_matrix

# Input matrix 1
variables_j_col_values_1 = [['C',   'X', 'B', 'U1', 'L2', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5'], 
                            ['+M', 'U1',   8,  1.0,    0,  2.0,  1.0, -1.0,    0,    0], 
                            ['+M', 'X4',   2,    0,    0,  1.0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                            [ 0.0, 'U2',   8,    0,  1.0,  1.0,  2.0,    0,    0, -1.0]]

# Input matrix 2
variables_j_col_values_2 = [['C',  'X', 'B', 'L1', 'L2', 'U1', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3'], 
                            ['+M', 'U1',  12,    0,    0,  1.0,  3.0,  2.0, -1.0], 
                            ['+M', 'L1',  12,  1.0,    0,    0,  2.0,  3.0,    0], 
                            ['+M', 'L2',   2,    0,  1.0,    0, -2.0,  1.0,    0]]

# Reorder the matrices
reordered_matrix_1 = reorder_matrix(variables_j_col_values_1)
reordered_matrix_2 = reorder_matrix(variables_j_col_values_2)

# Print the reordered matrices
print("Output for matrix 1:")
for row in reordered_matrix_1: print(row)

print("\nOutput for matrix 2:")
for row in reordered_matrix_2: print(row)
```

These matrices must be ordered according to their headers of the list of titles of the columns, that is to say, of the elements of the first sublist. So first go 'C', then go 'X', then go 'B', and then all X columns with a number after them (for example, X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, . ..), then the U columns with a number after them (for example, U1, U2, U3, U4, U5, ...) and finally the columns of have L and a number after them (for example, L1, L2, L3, L4, L5, ...)

Convert these matrices to these other matrices, thus:

```py
#output for matrix 1
variables_j_col_values = [[ 'C',  'X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'U1', 'L2'], 
                          ['+M', 'U1',   8,  2.0,  1.0, -1.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                          ['+M', 'X4', 1.0,  1.0,    0,  1.0,    0,    2,    0,    0], 
                          [ 0.0, 'U2',   8,  1.0,  2.0,    0,    0, -1.0,    0,  1.0]]

#output for matrix 2
variables_j_col_values = [[ 'C',  'X', 'B', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'U1', 'L1', 'L2'], 
                          ['+M', 'U1',  12,  3.0,  2.0, -1.0,  1.0,    0,    0], 
                          ['+M', 'L1',  12,  2.0,  3.0,    0,    0,  1.0,    0], 
                          ['+M', 'L2',   2, -2.0,  1.0,    0,    0,    0,  1.0]]
```

How to fix my code and get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas` to sort with your own function. Then export to an array again:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sorted_char = 'CXBUL'

def custom_sort(s): # building int from char position in sorted_char and remaining digits
    return [int(str(sorted_char.find(a[0])) + str(a[1:])) for a in s]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(variables_j_col_values_1)
print(df1.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, key=custom_sort).to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
[['C' 'X' 'B' 'X1' 'X2' 'X3' 'X4' 'X5' 'U1' 'L2']
 ['+M' 'U1' 8 2.0 1.0 -1.0 0 0 1.0 0]
 ['+M' 'X4' 2 1.0 1.0 0 1.0 0 0 0]
 [0.0 'U2' 8 1.0 2.0 0 0 -1.0 0 1.0]]
```

Similarly, for the second matrix:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(variables_j_col_values_2)
print(df2.sort_values(by=0, axis=1, key=custom_sort).to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
[['C' 'X' 'B' 'X1' 'X2' 'X3' 'U1' 'L1' 'L2']
 ['+M' 'U1' 12 3.0 2.0 -1.0 1.0 0 0]
 ['+M' 'L1' 12 2.0 3.0 0 0 1.0 0]
 ['+M' 'L2' 2 -2.0 1.0 0 0 0 1.0]]
```